# Можно ли говорить "элементарная невежественность"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Возник у нас с коллегами спор: можно ли говорить "элементарная невежественность" либо только "элементарное невежество" или "элементарная безграмотность"?

Answer (score 2):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

НЕВЕЖЕСТВО 1.Отсутствие знаний, необразованность, неосведомлённость в чём-л. Н. лектора, ученика, политика. Обнаружить своё н.Непростительное, удивительное н.
2. Разг. Неучтивый, невежливый поступок. Разговаривать с дамой сидя - н.

НЕВЕЖЕСТВЕННЫЙ, Необразованный, малосведущий. Н. человек. Н. в химии. //
Свойственный необразованным людям, вызванный невежеством.Н-ое суждение. < Невежественно, нареч. Н. рассуждать об экономике. Невежественность, -и; ж. Н. суждений. Н. в вопросах политики.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Невежа - невежливый, грубый человек, а невежда - малообразованный человек. Невежество  свойственно малообразованным людям, в то же время они могут быть невежливыми, несведущими в вопросах этикета.

Элементарное невежество - это отсутствие знаний, в том числе в этикете. Элементарная невежественность - это поведение невежественного человека, в котором проявляется его невежество (малообразованность).

Answer (score 1):

Слово "невежественность" существует, почему бы и не быть ей *элементарной*...

Answer (score 1):

Смотря в каких случаях. Если речь о свойстве характера - невежественность, о проявлении этого свойства в определённом случае - невежество.

Чаще всего идёт речь об элементарном невежестве как о проявлении свойства невежественного человека. Так что это синонимы, различающиеся когда-то оттенками смысла (невежественность - частный случай невежества), а сейчас воспринимаются как полные синонимы, так что возможны все три случая, кроме разговорного, невежество как невежливость, грубость.